# How many types of intelligence or dimension of mind?

Tags: mind, buddhi

Western science rejects every concept until they don't cut and see because its reach is limited and under development and based on one type of intelligence ie intellect. Many of scriptures are lost, Nalanda university was burnt and Somnath was destroyed.  A lot of precious knowledge is lost but somewhere it still exists in other forms or derived forms.

How many types of intelligence or dimension of mind?

My question is different from linked target question. What I mean to ask here is the types of intelligence which come before receiving knowledge not after the knowledge or after effect of *bodh*, which affect the human body. Hope now it clarifies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Description of 7 bhumikas of Patañjala Yoga Sutras](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24294/description-of-7-bhumikas-of-pata%c3%b1jala-yoga-sutras)

Comment: Pls.see above question the answer of 7 types of prajna is also there.

Comment: I think so, this 7 intelligence was told by sadhguru, when he was telling our rituals or sacrifice is not wrong. Its wrong when we forget that our science fundamental changes when we move from one dimension to another one. As new laws apply and govern there.But I am not confirm about yoga-sutras.

Comment: Ok ,If you think your query is same then pls.close this question as duplicate or else do try to modify it in different direction.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar thanks for the help, but that question tells after effect of knowledge gain and intelligence cycle change taking place.

Comment: Confusing the number 7 which is common in our religion with anything related to 7 could mislead us.

Comment: My question doesn't want votes, all I look for an answer, if not here I will ask it somewhere else if not there I will create something my own, but right now this place looks apt, why to reinvent the wheel. I will try to clarify it more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82174/discussion-between-theexorcist-and-swiftpushkar).

Comment: @bharata adding timeline doesn't make sense, however, if you can add any other detail to my question, which could help the foreigners to understand the question and our scientific religion.you are welcome.

Comment: @TheExorcist, adding timeline makes sense, because I have already answered your question at this time and my answer after your edit looks like a wrong answer. Please add a timeline.

Comment: @Bharata Make sense if that follows the community guidelines. Your answer was the wrong one since you put a great effort so I didn't downvote it.

Comment: @UdayKrishnaI agree your comment is correct, but I have to discard your reason: he also says westernism has taught us to constantly look at everything with logic and intellect.  Rene has deeply studied everything with great effort but under the effect of logic, what if I say we cannot define everything with logic, we never use the logic when our greet our elders, we just do it. The universe is very big, everything cannot be explained with logic, so I believe there must be something else to understand and our scriptures have listed it, but right now we might be unaware.

Comment: For example- ancient scriptures foretold us the distance between earth and moon or the time to reach the earth, they also told us the quantum physics. Later after 2000 years when scientist realized newtonian mechanics doesnt apply to quantum particle, they discovered quantum physics. But prior to this everybody was discarding it inspite of its presence. whence discovered it helped them understand. Haldi or turmeric was tried patented and marijuana has many medicinal property but USA banned it in India, while them are using them to find cure for cancer.So no western, we have all.

Comment: Sure I liked the link you provided but it does not go through my path to answer.

Comment: if you think so that your answer is close to my question, you are welcome to add it, the community is self-sufficient to decide, if it fulfils the purpose, it will be accepted else we all have the option to try constantly.

Comment: Which sadguru told? If it is Isha I feel sorry for you.  For the whole world Adiguru is Dattratreya  [first incarnation] and Sadguru is Sainath [last incarnation] in Guru Parampara. Can you tell who gave Isha   sadguru?Pl try to modify the question.

Comment: As far as I understood, the more We move away from intelligence related debates, the more We progress spiritually. Intelligence is the offshoot of EGO. @TheExorcist

Answer (score 3):

To first of all I would like to say that your question has the big mistake from the Vedic sight because the concepts of mind and intellect have a big difference. The Intelligence is not a dimension of mind!

**BG (Bhagavad Gita) 3.42** gives the hierarchy of different subtle and gross elements within a particular body:

`Spirit with soul` **→** `Intelligence` **→** `Mind` **→** `Senses` **→** `Dull matter`

**Function of Intelligence (the buddhi or the intellect)**

The function of the intelligence, under the guidance of the soul, is to direct the mind but the mind, over a long period of time, has become difficult to direct. Instead, the mind has become so powerful that it dictates the intelligence and controls the soul, just ‘*as an acute infection may surpass the efficacy of medicine*’.

**Nature of Mind**

Lord Krishna tells Arjuna that, *“one must deliver himself with the help of his mind, and not degrade himself. The mind is the friend of the conditioned soul, and his enemy as well.”* (BG 6.5). And *“for him who has conquered the mind, the mind is the best of friends; but for one who has failed to do so, his mind will remain the greatest enemy.”* (BG 6.6).

**Difference between the Mind and the Intelligence**

Initially a warning on the outside of the cigarette packet used to be *“smoking is harmful to health”*. Later this warning became more grave and it read as *“smoking causes cancer”*. But the latest warning is the most serious ie *“smoking kills”*.

The intelligence understands and wants to follows this advice but the powerful mind says, *“don’t listen to the intelligence and enjoy full the life – have another drag”*.

**Purpose of the intelligence**

To control the mind, follows the instructions of the soul and ultimately the Supersoul, under the guidance of a bonafide guru, and help the soul to achieve the ultimate goal of life.

---

### Answer to your question

> **Attention:** *this is an answer to the **[3. version of this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/revisions/28798/3)***. After this version this question was changed and additional information was puted.
>
> To change the question meaning (you have added not only the **[link to the video "Sadhguru: «Developing an Inclusive Consciousness» | Talks At Google"](https://youtu.be/QQn8X4FbpTM?t=889)**) after the question was answered is not allowed on StackOverflow / StackExchange. And it is very disrespectful because I have already answered your question at this time and my answer after your edit now looks like a wrong answer..

**Jnana Bhumikas (Stages of Wisdom)**

The Varaha Upanishad lists seven stages of wisdom. These stages mark the journey from striving for truth until the final state of self realization. These seven stages belong to the realm of jnana yoga (the yoga of knowledge).

**The seven stages of wisdom are:**

- *Subheccha (Yearning for Truth)*. In this state, there is a strong will to study scriptures and to practise them. The spiritual aspirant longs to mingle with gurus and teachers. He/she has a strong yearning to realize the self.
- *Vicharana (Enquiry, Investigation)*. This stage is marked by deep inquiry. The aspirant puts the teachings into practice through self-inquiry and meditation.
- *Tanumanasi (Thread-like Mind)*.The practice of meditation and inquiry transforms the aspirant’s mind. He/she slowly loses interest in worldly affairs and passions, and starts to concentrate more on spiritual practice. The mind slowly moves away from desires and emotions, and longs to pursue selfless spirituality.
- *Sattvapatti (Attaining Purity)*. In this stage, the mind becomes pure. The lower qualities of passion (rajas) and dullness (tamas) are transformed into purity (sattva) and awareness. A pure mind is akin to a lake’s calm surface. It is able to directly perceive the Absolute Self. Deep rooted tendencies in the mind are destroyed and the aspirant breaks frees from the clutches of maya (illusion) and sees the world as a dream.
- *Asamsakti (Detachment)*. In this stage, the aspirant becomes completely detached. He/she becomes utterly selfless and inwardly experiences complete bliss. He/she is not affected by external circumstances, but still performs voluntary actions, when the need arises. The aspirant becomes a jivanmukta (liberated while alive).
- *Padartha (Continuous Awareness of the Self)*. In this stage, the person is continuously immersed in the Absolute Self and acts only when impelled by others.
- *Turiya (The Superconscious State)*. In this final stage, the aspirant sees the world and the Absolute Self as one. Ramana Maharishi said turiya is natural and real state of one’s self.

**Conclusion**
These seven stages can be used a guide to gauge spiritual progress. If you are a spiritual aspirant, check which stage you currently in, and strive to improve further.

**How to do all this?**

The biggest influence to control the mind is to do yoga exercises (inclusive Pranayama) and obligatorily to change your food to sattvic food **only**. Without this you has no chance to control your mind.

Comment: thank you for an answer, and maybe you are right that mind and intelligence are different,  but questions ask the types of intelligence which a human body sees the object. For example- modern science uses one type - intellect which tells if we cut substance there is the atom, further cut it down we move to 3 particles, further moving inward, quantum particles are met, what lies beyond is still a mystery or under development.

Comment: What you wrote is already answered in another question stating  7 prajnas, but when I watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQn8X4FbpTM  I was confused as he said 4 not 7 otherwise I would accept this 7 thing as my answer.

Comment: I never had the intention to change my question, all I did  so that everybody could understand my question, however in absence of a proper answer, I am still looking, I will keep editing the content, but not the question, since sadhguru said dimension of mind, but there is no term like dimension of mind, these are very cosmic question, people don't think on such thing. Maybe my brain understands well, but unable to express it in English in spite of being an expert user of English.

Comment: I edited the question and its content even got confused with this concept. Spirit with soul → Intelligence → Mind → Senses → Dull matter, which says intelligence is a superset of mind, implies to tell me that there is a possibility  of intelligence coming from other than the brain. Had you not written this line(enlightened one) {Spirit with soul → Intelligence → Mind → Senses → Dull matter}    I would never come to know these two are different. partially your answer is correct. But I am waiting for another community members to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

After listening to speech given by Sadhguru, it is that he is talking about the four functional aspects ( dimensions) of mind ( Mind in Western sense, but Antahkarana as per Vendanta) which is Manas, Buddhi, Chitta and Ahamkara. These are functional aspects, but core feature of mind is the continuously emanating thoughts. By such a classification, a person is able to better understand mind and have control over it. In his speech, Sadhguru says that in the modern world we use Buddhi ( intellect) aspect of our mind mostly.In his speech at 10:17 of [his lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQn8X4FbpTM) he names all dimensions of the mind. At 14:58 which this question has pointed out, Sadhguru says "next dimension of intellect is ahamkara" but from 10:17, it is clear that he meant that the next dimension of mind(not intellect) is ahamkara.